How do I create a valid XRechnung without a VAT of the customer?
When validating an XRechnung created by odoo 16 (Odoo 16.0-20240522 (Community Edition)), I received the following (slightly misleading) message “Buyer electronic address MUST be provided (val-sch.2.1; PEPPOL-EN16931-RO-10)” After researching, this error message says that the customer's email address is missing. However, adding this does not change anything. I then found out that the customer does not have a VAT number. If I enter any number there, the validation is successful. Unfortunately, the validation also fails if I enter a “/” there, as suggested in the small help for the field. 
What do I have to set in odoo so that valid XRechnung are created even if the customer does not have a VAT number?

I believe you are using the code "9930" for the German VAT number.
You can use a different value for the electronic address.
For example, the code "EM" stands for "Electronic mail."
You can find the relevant code list (EAS) here: https://www.xrepository.de/details/urn:xoev-de:kosit:codeliste:eas_5#version.
More information about the field "Buyer Electronic Address" (BT-49) can be found in the XRechnung specification, Chapter 11.3. https://xeinkauf.de/app/uploads/2024/07/302-XRechnung-2024-06-20.pdf
